# Qt: OpenGL textures don't render (appear black) in debug mode only

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures, qimage

When I run my program in debug mode, the textures don't appear  (but the triangles still render).
And yes, with this I mean the textures load fine when running in release mode.

Any idea on why this may happen?

During my paintGl() call:

```
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tiles[x]->image.width(), tiles[x]->image.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tiles[x]->image.bits());
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, tiles[x]->vertices.size());
```

my images are stored in my own class within a QImage, and formatted with the "QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat()" function.

Comment: The most likely cause is some kind of memory management issue. E.g. using memory after it has been freed, or not allocating enough memory.

Comment: Sounds like an uninitialised variable to me, though in code you're not showing us.